# Retrofit POST java.io.EOFException occurs when I append parameters

Tags: java, android, web-services, post, retrofit

I am using retrofit API for POST request it works fine for me if I use it to request without sending any parameter like this:

```
@POST("/api/basic/all")
void postFeedCat(Callback<AllNews> callback);
```

But when I want to try this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/news/all")
void postFeedNews(@Field("news_Id") String news_Id, Callback<AllNews> callback);
```

it returns

```
  retrofit.RetrofitError: java.io.EOFException
```

but if this is tried more than one time it works successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. In Android 4.4 they work with OkHttpclient so thats the reason why it is working on 4.4 and not on the older Android versions.

To solve this add a dependency in gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.5.1'
```

and create a new client like this:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
```

add that new client to the restadapter to use this:

```
setClient(new OkClient(client))
```

The error should be solved now.